# Способ определения четности JavaScript

Tags: javascript

В книге нашел способ определения четности:

```js
function isEven(n) {
  if (n == 0) return true;
  else if (n == 1) return false;
  else return isEven(n - 2);
}

console.log(isEven(50));
// → true
console.log(isEven(75));
// → false
```

То, что если `n = 0 true` (четное) и если `1` то `false` (нечетное), я понимаю. Но почему при добавлении этой строки `else return isEven(n - 2);` любое число начинает определяться как `false` либо `true`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Поздравляю, Вы первый раз столкнулись с рекурсией. Для ее понимания необходимо некоторое умственное усилие.

```js
function isEven(n) {
  if (isNaN(n) || n < 0) // guard against bad input
    return;

  if (n == 0) 
    return true;
  else if (n == 1) 
    return false;
  else { 
    console.log("cannot decide yet, call isEven again with (", n, "- 2 )");
    return isEven(n - 2);
  }
}

console.log(isEven(20));
```

Comment: . Спасибо, сначала не понял о чем Вы, пока не запустил код в консоли.

Comment: @ArtemShulga Пожалуйста. Успехов! Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.

Answer (score 2):

Эта строка - рекурсивный вызов той же функции, а на вход ей дается `исходное число - 2` Рекурсия работает до тех пор, пока исходное число не станет `<=1`

Comment: Спасибо за помощь.